# Перенаправление не работает

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Перенаправление не работает header(). В другом сайте работает.  Думаю, проблема в сервере, но не знаю, в чем.

```
   <?php
    session_start();
    include_once '../inc/db.php';
    include_once 'header.php';
    $test = new db();
    $fetch = $test->work() ;

    if (isset($_GET["is_exit"])) { 
        if ($_GET["is_exit"] == 1) {
            $test->out(); 
            header("Location: ?is_exit=0"); 
        }
    }
    if ($test->isAuth()) { 
$blablabla
?>
   <b>blabla</b>

    <?php
    if($_FILES){
      $blabla 
    }

    }
    else {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`header("Location: index.php");`  - отправка заголовка, это должно быть до любого вывода.

У вас выше по коду  идет вывод `<b>blabla</b>`.

Comment: В другом сайте работает, а в этом нет. Код один и тот, @Ale_x.

Comment: Можете показать пример? @Ale_x

Comment: Я делаю редиректы так:

    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit();

Comment: В любом случае до вызова header не должно быть вывода. Если вам надо показать сообщение, а потом выполнить редирект, воспользуйтесь 

`header("refresh:5;url=page.php")`

а потом выполните вывод информации. Пользователю будет показано сообщение, и через указанное время `5` перейдет дальше (`page.php`).